# ¿Problema con jQuery y Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

He estado tratando de conseguir la respuesta desde el servidor usando una función entre jQuery y Ajax, pero por mas que envío la información desde el formulario no tengo respuesta alguna de mi petición. No se que sucede, porque el Ajax no me da ningún tipo de respuesta.

Aquí parte del código HTML.

```
        <div class="container">

          <section class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
              <h2 class="tituloLogin">Iniciar Sesión</h2>
              <form id="login">
                <div class="inputRojo input-group mb-3 mr-sm-2">
                  <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                  <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail">
                </div>

                <div class="inputRojo input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
                  <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                  <input type="password" id="passwd" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña">
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="btnContrasenaLogin mb-3">¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</a>
                <button onclick="login()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Ingresar</button>        
                </form>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block mb-4"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i> Ingresar con Facebook</button>

                <a href="#" class="btnRegistrarme mb-3">Registrarme</a>

              </form>

            </div>
          </section>

        </div>
```

Y aquí esta mi función, la cual esta contenida en un archivo Javascript.

```
    function login() {

        var em = $('#email').val();
        var pa = $('#passwd').val();

        alert(em);
        alert(pa);

        var url = 'http://www.kupomcity.com/gamma/api_v2.php?_opt=user&_act=login';

        var data = {
        email: 'em',
        passwd: 'pa'
        };  

      $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert(data);    
      });    
      }
```

Comment: A que te refieres con que no da respuesta? [Funciona perfectamente](http://jsbin.com/viqapexipi/edit?js,console) solo que el login da error. Al parecer usuario/contraseña invalido.

Comment: Para que `login()` funcione el DOM debe estar cargado, en el código no veo que hagas esa verificación. Y también por supuesto, debes incluir la librería jQuery para que funcione.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando creas la variable `data` le asignas el texto **em** y **pa** a las llaves `email` y `passwd` respectivamente, y no el valor de las variables `em` y `pa`, quitale las comillas tal vez por eso no te funciona.